# How to change the slot (channel) in a mixer?

Tags: sibelius

How to change the slot (channel) of an instrument in a mixer in Sibelius? Now this field is inactive, it cannot be changed. Also, it changes automatically for all tracks when you select an instrument. Can I turn this off somehow?